# Can someone help me with this De Morgan's Law question?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

[image: This is how far I've got so far]. We have been learning about boolean algebra in school and can't figure out what to do for this question. Can anyone help explain the steps?

Comment: Who downvoted?!

Comment: Who removed my image?!

Comment: It looks good so far.  Your next step is to use the hint, then distribution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\overline{(\overline A+B)(A+\overline B)}=\overline{(\overline A+B)}+\overline{(A+\overline B)}=A\overline B+\overline AB$$

by De Morgan, and by the tip
$$(A+B)(\overline A+\overline B)=A\overline A+ A\overline B+B\overline A+\overline B B=A\overline B+\overline AB.$$